# HTTPS Request From a Credential Provider DLL

Tags: winlogon, credential-providers

I've been creating a Credential Provider DLL that authenticates via the internet before allowing login. However this hasn't worked as well as I expected because my WinHTTP request isn't getting sent. I've confirmed this using wire shark. but I can't figure out why it's not sending any requests off. I've checked that my code is actually calling the functions properly - and they are. But the http request never makes it off. I'm slightly confused at this point and I'm seeking to know if there is some blanket block against https Requests at login.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing. Could you by chance share a little code?  It would both help people answer your question and help me get started on mine as well.

Comment: ok I solved it. Basic format is 'WinHttpOpen (), WinHttpConnect(), WinHttpOpen(), WinHttpConnect(), WinHttpOpenRequest(), WinHttpSendRequest(), WinHttpRecieveResponse(), WinHttpQueryHeaders()'

Comment: Hello, could you explain a bit more? I think I encountered the same bug: I have a credential provider communicating over the network, and it works perfectly on Windows 7, but on Vista, no packets are exchanged (checked with wireshark too, and without firewall). Do you know the cause?

Comment: I've solved it by using libcurl and doing whatever I want, HTTP or HTTPS requests.

Comment: I stuck with the same problem, where i have to make my https? can you post the sample working code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ [CP-V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/credential-provider/), so you can use easily from [CPPRESTSDK](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk) library.

Note: You must note the DNS address and the digital certificate you are using must be valid.